# Creating a 10x10 image grid using easel.js where images cross dissolve randomly

Tags: javascript, easeljs

Creating something I'm hoping is easy using Easel.js, but still a novice. Simply want to create a 10X10 image grid where each of the images will cross dissolve to another paired image at random intervals.

Can anyone point me to any similar examples or will I need to hard code this using only javascript instead?

Eventually I will load these images from a server but first I need a working demo without any server ajax calls, just load images locally.

Comment: must you use easel? better off using canvas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by cross dissolve you mean fade into each other, then you might want to take a look at the [createjs.AlphaMaskFilter](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/AlphaMaskFilter.html) or the [createjs.AlphaMapFilter](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/AlphaMapFilter.html).To load an image take a look here: [The Image doesn't show up on the Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324384/the-image-doesnt-show-up-on-the-canvas)
There really is no difference between an image on a server and a local image, it might be even easier from a server.